# Question about extension theorem on uniqueness and existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm  studying ordinary differential equations from Ordinary differential equations and Dynamical Systems by Gerald Teschl, and i came across the following theorem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AQfM.jpg[image]

I have a couple of question regarding the theorem

**1**. I'm not really getting the conclusion of the theorem, before this, the book stated that the idea behind the theorem is to avoid the restriction from the Lipschitz Constant that we have in the fundamental theorem of existence and uniqueness, but i really don't see how is this happening, so any help would be appreciated.

**2**. in addition to **1** could someone give me a example where i can see how does the theorem works?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As the comment before the theorem states, it avoids the restriction $T_0<L^{-1}$ and hence gives better estimates for the maximal existence time $T_0$. See Problem 2.9 for an example.