# Global existence of solutions of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be Lipschitz continuous, and let $x(t)$ be the solution of the differential equation $\dot{x}(t) = F(x)$ with the initial value $x(0) = x_0 \neq 0$. Show that:

If for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the condition $\langle F(x), x \rangle = F(x)^T x \leq \|x\|^2$ holds, then $x(t)$ exists for all times $t > 0$.

So I assume you first show with the Picard–Lindelöf theorem that $x(t)$ exist for $t$ within the interval $t \in [t_0 - \delta, t_0 + \delta]$. Then you extend interval and show with the condition that x(t) goes for all $t>0$

I dont know if this is the right approach, help would be appreciated

Comment: I would have thought you would use $$\langle F, x \rangle = \langle \dot{x}, x \rangle$$ and then apply [Gronwalls inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality), similarly to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046758/application-of-gronwall-inequality-to-existence-of-solutions). But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Matthew Cassell: yes, this is the idea. One can start from the existence of a unique maximal solution (follows from F being Lipschitz-continuous) and proceed as you have indicated.